# nginx serve from different static directory based on user-agent

Tags: nginx

i have directory structure like this:

```
HTML
|
|--android/
|--ios/
```

In short i have 2 directory(ios & android) in HTML/

Both directory contains index.html . In android/index.html there is **link** to ../ios &  In ios/index.html there is **link** to ../android for switching user from ios to android & android to ios..

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /home/vishant/HTML;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name wishfeed.l;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

my nginx configuration is like given above..

How to serve directory if user agent is ios / if user agent is android.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10627596/309483 ?

Answer (score 7):

The [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) can generate an appropriate document root from the `user-agent` string down.

For example:

```
map $http_user_agent $root {
    "~*android" /home/vishant/HTML/android;
    "~iPhone" /home/vishant/HTML/ios;
    default /home/vishant/HTML;
}
```

*You will have to work on the regular expressions yourself, as I do not know if they are right for all cases.*

The above `map` block is placed above the `server` block within the `http` context of the configuration file. In this case, it creates a variable called `$root` which may be used within the `server` block.

---

If you need to serve the entire site's content from either subdirectory, use `$root` to set the global `root` like this:

```
server {
    ...
    root $root;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you only want the URI `/index.html` to be affected, use `$root` within a location. For example:

```
location = /index.html {
    root $root;
}
```